# Single multithread Java Client with DataStax Java Driver for Apache Cassandra not utilizing system resources

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

I’d appreciate any guidance on optimal setup for multi-threaded, **high throughput low latency Java Client using DataStax Java Driver for Apache Cassandra**. I appreciate ‘roll-your-own’ bench-marking is not recommended, but this task is also aimed at a proof-of-concept for a real-world application to achieve high TPS.

### Setup:

**Client Side** : Java 8 Client, configurable number of multi-threaded executor threads (facilitated by lmax disruptor), **cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar**, running on Redhat 6.3, 24 core machine, dl360s
**Server side** : 3 node Cassandra Cluster (**apache-cassandra-2.2.4**, on Redhat 6 with Java 8) , Replication Factor = 3 , running on Redhat 6.3, 24 core machine dl360s

### Testing

With cl=LOCAL_QUORUM tests have been in the region of **3.5K INSERTS and 6.5K READS** per second from a relatively simple schema, with latency circa 6 and 2 milliseconds respectively, with CPU usage circa 20% across the box.

### Problem

However the problem I can not solve is that - **when I create multiple separate instances of my load client-application I can achieve significantly higher TPS summed across instances, and greater CPU usage than I can ever achieve within a single JVM**.  This suggests that my Java Client Application is neither IO or CPU bound, nor is the server-side Cassandra cluster the bottleneck. Likewise when I stub out the Cassandra call, I achieve much higher TPS thus giving me confidence that the application is not suffering from any contention.

So my question is: Is this a common problem – that one single Java Client using DataStax Java Driver for Apache Cassandra is somehow limited on it’s throughput? and assuming not can anyone point me in the right direction to investigate.

I have tested multiple sequences (READs and WRITEs), and also both execute and executeAsync, with variable number of concurrent threads. As you’d expect I see higher numbers with executeAsync but still the same limitation within my app.

I have tested with multiple Connection Pooling settings, and have tried creating/building 1 Cluster Instance per client-application, and multiple cluster instances per application, and varying CoreConnections, maxRequestsPerConnection and newConnectionThreshold values but thus far with no success.

My current best results were with 50 executor threads, 5 instances ;MaxRequestsPerConnection(L) = 1024; ;NewConnectionThreshold(L) = 800; CoreConnectionsPerHost(L) = 20

This yielded ~4K TPS BUT only using 18% of the CPU, and when I start a separate Application Instance I achieve 7.5K TPS across both using 30% CPU, but I can not achieve this 7.5K within the save JVM

Code: Create Cluster

```
    LoadBalancingPolicy tokenAwarePolicy =
            new TokenAwarePolicy(new RoundRobinPolicy());
    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPoints(node)
            .withLoadBalancingPolicy(tokenAwarePolicy)
            .withPoolingOptions(new PoolingOptions()) // Have tried various options here
            .build();
```

Code: Prepare Statement (once)

```
        String insertSqlString =  "INSERT INTO " + keySpaceName + ".test_three ("
                + "user_id, field_a, field_b, field_c, field_d) values "
                + "( ?, ?, ?, ?);";
        statementInsertDataTablePS = session.prepare(insertSqlString);
        statementInsertDataTablePS.setConsistencyLevel(configuredConsistencyLevel); //2
```

Code: Execute

```
    BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(statementInsertDataTablePS);

  session.executeAsync(boundStatement.bind(
            sequence,  // userID
            sequence + "value_for_field_a", 
            sequence + "value_for_field_b", 
            sequence + "value_for_field_c", 
            sequence + "value_for_field_d") );
```

Comment: Can you share your code or provide an example?   C* stress, which uses the java driver, for example is shown to be capable of achieving over 200k requests/sec

Comment: Thanks @Andy - I will add

Comment: Hi, @Aidan, did you get an explanation of this behaviour or maybe any improvements? Thanks for question!